# Events not generated in this C# winform which uses azure services for converting speech to text

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, azure, speech-to-text

I have this c# winform which uses azure speech to text for converting speech into text. This winform has one checkbox for speech on/off and performs continuous speech recognition until I close the window . The problem is , when I check the checkbox only session started event is generated and nothing else happen , no other events like  Recognizing, Recognized , canceled is generating . Do you know what is going wrong ?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech;

namespace CsharpSTTform
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private async void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (checkBox1.Checked) await SpeechContinuousRecognitionAsync();
        }



        public async Task SpeechContinuousRecognitionAsync()
        {
            // Creates an instance of a speech config with specified subscription key and service region.
            // Replace with your own subscription key and service region (e.g., "westus").
            var config = SpeechConfig.FromSubscription("api key", "westus");

            // Creates a speech recognizer from microphone.
            using (var recognizer = new SpeechRecognizer(config))
            {
                // Subscribes to events.
                recognizer.Recognizing += (s, e) =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"RECOGNIZING: Text={e.Result.Text}");
                };

                recognizer.Recognized += (s, e) =>
                {
                    var result = e.Result;
                    Console.WriteLine($"Reason: {result.Reason.ToString()}");
                    if (result.Reason == ResultReason.RecognizedSpeech)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"Final result: Text: {result.Text}.");
                    }
                };

                recognizer.Canceled += (s, e) =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"\n    Recognition Canceled. Reason: {e.Reason.ToString()}, CanceledReason: {e.Reason}");
                };

                recognizer.SessionStarted += (s, e) =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\n    Session started event.");
                };

                recognizer.SessionStopped += (s, e) =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\n    Session stopped event.");
                };

                // Starts continuous recognition. Uses StopContinuousRecognitionAsync() to stop recognition.
                await recognizer.StartContinuousRecognitionAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

            }
        }


    }
}
```

when I check the checkbox the initial output I get is :

```
  Session started event.
The thread 0x3274 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

After some time I got this output:

```
Session started event.
The thread 0x3274 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x5880 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x9e8 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Comment: Why are you doing `Console.WriteLine()` in a winforms app? Did you mean `Debug.WriteLine()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `recognizer` variable is a **local variable** of method `SpeechContinuousRecognitionAsync`, and it gets disposed right at the end of the `using` block, which is probably *almost immediately*.

If you change it to be an instance variable instead, and created without a `using` construct, then it will stay in memory.

You can then later `Dispose()` it if and when needed.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private SpeechRecognizer recognizer; // <-- instance variable

    public async Task SpeechContinuousRecognitionAsync()
    {
        var config = SpeechConfig.FromSubscription("api key", "westus");

        // Create a speech recognizer from microphone.
        recognizer = new SpeechRecognizer(config);

        recognizer.Recognizing += (s, e) =>
        {
            // ...
        };

        // ... rest of initialization
    }
}
```